# themedata.thmx and colorschememapping.xml from word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am saving files from word as an html file.

Word creates a subfolder with three files:

- colorschememapping.xml
- filelist.xml
- themedata.thmx

What do these files do? When do I need these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are metadata files about Word formtting that are not used in the browser but help Word reconstruct the document as a Word document if you open the html file in Word.

Word is not a very good web page editor and creates a bunch of code that has nothing to do with display in a browser.

To be sure, make a backup of the folder containing these metadata files in a different location. Then delete the folder and open the file in your browser. You should experience no difference. If you open the file in Word you may or may not see any difference but the information in those files will not be used. If your document did not have changes to the default theme, you will see no difference.

**Note: if the folder contains image files, do not delete the folder or you will lose the images.**

Comment: When I'm deleting this folder, the pictures are not correctly displayed.

Comment: I would suggest posting your own question, (with a link to this one). Specify which folders you are talking about and whether you are displaying in a browser or the Word application.